# Implement Custom aggregation in Mysql Query

Tags: javascript, sql, mysql, typescript

Here is the table

```
id | module_id | rating

1  |        421   | 3          
2  |        421   | 5        
3. |        5321  | 4          
4  |        5321  | 5           
5  |        5321  | 4              
6  |        641   | 2   
7  |        641   | 3           
8  |        641   | 3            
9  |        641   | 2          
10 |        7201  | 4          
11 |        7201  | 4               
12 |        7201  | 3           
+------------+-----------------+------------------+-----------------------+---------------------------------------------+
```

In my code, i'm fecthing ratings of a module id and sorting them using a custom formula. and sorting the module ids in descending order with respect to the formula value

here is my code

```
let arr = [421,5321,641,7201];
let temp = [], ci_bounds = [];
for(let j=0; j<arr.length; j++){
    let id = arr[j];
    let ratings = execute("select * from table where module_id = " + id);
    if(ratings.length>0){
        for(let k=0; k<ratings.length; k++){
            const rat = ratings[k];
            if(rat.rating > 3){
                pos++;
            }else if(rat.rating <= 3){
                neg++;
            }
        }
        let lower_bound = ((pos + 1.9208) / (pos + neg) - 1.96 * Math.sqrt((pos * neg) / (pos + neg) + 0.9604) / (pos + neg)) / (1 + 3.8416 / (pos + neg));
        ci_bounds[j] = lower_bound;
        temp[j] = [arr[j], ci_bounds[j]];
        pos=0; neg=0;
    }else{
        temp[j] = [arr[j], 0];
    }
   let un_empty = temp.filter(function (el) {
      return el != null;
   });
}
```

Here in temp array i have sub-arrays with first element is module_id and second element is lowerbound.

```
temp value for above data
[
    [
        421,
        0.09452865480086611
    ],
    [
        5321,
        0.43849391955098216
    ],
    [
        641,
        2.8316237110415135e-17
    ],
    [
        7201,
        0.20765495512648788
    ]
]
```

and i'm sorting the above input arr with these lower_bounds. so that my final answer array should be reordered format of above input `arr` according to lower_bound in desc order.

```
let sortedArray = un_empty.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b[1] - a[1];
});

sortedArray output - 
[
    [
        5321,
        0.43849391955098216
    ],
    [
        7201,
        0.20765495512648788
    ],
    [
        421,
        0.09452865480086611
    ],
    [
        641,
        2.8316237110415135e-17
    ] 
]
arr = sortedArray;
let sorting = [];
for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    const id_arr = arr[i][1];
    for(let j=0; j<id_arr.length; j++){
        y[j] = id_arr[j][0];
    }
    sorting.push(y);
    y = [];
}
Final ans:  sorting = [5321, 7201, 421, 641];
```

Can we do this above aggregation in query itself?.

Comment: Please could you share your desired result set?

Comment: @RobEyre Edited the question with result set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with a subquery to calculate the values for `pos` and `neg` for each `module_id`, then an outer query to calculate `lower_bound`:

```
SELECT
    module_id,
    ((pos + 1.9208) / (pos + neg) - 1.96 * SQRT((pos * neg) / (pos + neg) + 0.9604) / (pos + neg)) / (1 + 3.8416 / (pos + neg)) as lower_bound
FROM (
    SELECT module_id, SUM(rating > 3) AS pos, SUM(rating <= 3) AS neg
    FROM ratings
    GROUP BY module_id
) posneg
ORDER BY lower_bound DESC;
```

That gives a result like this:

```
+-----------+------------------------+
| module_id | lower_bound            |
+-----------+------------------------+
|      5321 |    0.43849391932274523 |
|      7201 |    0.20765495508553936 |
|       421 |    0.09452865480086611 |
|       641 | 2.8316237110415135e-17 |
+-----------+------------------------+
```

If you just want the `module_id` values, then you can shift the calculation of `lower_bound` to the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT
    module_id
FROM (
    SELECT module_id, SUM(rating > 3) AS pos, SUM(rating <= 3) AS neg
    FROM ratings
    GROUP BY module_id
) posneg
ORDER BY
    ((pos + 1.9208) / (pos + neg) - 1.96 * SQRT((pos * neg) / (pos + neg) + 0.9604) / (pos + neg)) / (1 + 3.8416 / (pos + neg))
    DESC;
```

produces:

```
+-----------+
| module_id |
+-----------+
|      5321 |
|      7201 |
|       421 |
|       641 |
+-----------+
```

If you want to specify particular `module_id` values, then you can insert these (using JavaScript) into your SQL query.  You'll also need to modify the SQL query a little bit - see the example below which shows 5321, 421, 641, 7201 and 26 (which is not present in the ratings table, so gets a lower_bound value of zero):

```
SELECT
    module_id
FROM (
    SELECT t.column_0 as module_id, SUM(rating > 3) AS pos, SUM(rating <= 3) AS neg
    FROM (VALUES
        ROW(421),
        ROW(5321),
        ROW(641),
        ROW(7201),
        ROW(26)
    ) t
    LEFT JOIN ratings ON t.column_0 = ratings.module_id
    GROUP BY t.column_0
) posneg
ORDER BY
    ((pos + 1.9208) / (pos + neg) - 1.96 * SQRT((pos * neg) / (pos + neg) + 0.9604) / (pos + neg)) / (1 + 3.8416 / (pos + neg))
    DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!. but i have one more usecase here, lets say input arr contains one more module_id which is not present in table. then according to the above code  lowerbound will be 0. lets say ```arr = [421,5321,641,7201, 26]```  and the module_id order should be ```[5321, 7201, 421, 641, 26]```. How can we implement this?

Comment: Where is your definitive list of `module_id`s that should be included - is that in another table, or is that in JavaScript?

Comment: list is present in the javascript

Comment: You can either pass the `module_id` values into the SQL using eg `VALUES ROW(421),ROW(5321),ROW(641),ROW(7201),ROW(26)` - and then fetch them back again, which seems redundant, or else just parse the result you get back from SQL and add any missing module_ids on the end.  Probably easier to do it in JavaScript, if that's where the source data is

Comment: yes i get that, we can add missing ids in the end, just curious to know is there any way to implement in query itseld. In the above solution, i've checked by passing list of module_ids in sub query part like this ```From ratings where module_id in (421, 5321, 641, 7201, 26) Group BY module_id ``` but in the result 26 wont be present because entry is present not in table right?

Comment: I updated the answer to show an example of the kind of query you would need to generate - the key part is in the middle where you're specifying the `module_id` values in a sub-select, then `LEFT JOIN`ing to the `ratings` table.  (NB this is for MySQL v8 or above, if you're on a lower version you'll have to use a set of `SELECT 421 AS column_0 UNION ALL SELECT 5321 UNION ALL ...` statements).  Up to you to write the JavaScript that prepares this query :)